# How to remove content after last slash in the url withouth reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I have a url that looks like this

http://foo.com/Item/newItemName

After some operation on the page the item gets saved to the database with the item name. Now I want to replace the url like this

http://foo.com/Item/12345

I need to update the window state, so is it possible to update the url using window.history.replaceState method or something similar to that?

Comment: you talking about state, are you using a javascript framework in prticular?

Comment: Have you even tried to do this by yourself? If the answer is "yes" and there was a problem with your solution, you should post the code that does not work.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco I'm using TypeScript framework.

Comment: @mdziekon I tried, but I couldn't figure it out. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Then you should post the code that did not work. It's easier to help you this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Show me the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `pushState` function.

Check these docs out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Also, check out this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

The `pushState` function is super handy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Push state is not replacing newItemName with newItemId though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Mind adding some code, it sounds like you are replacing the state of the url without tacking on the current url.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like:

```
history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
```

Where `newUrl` is the new url which should replace the current one. Note this is HTML5 only.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `replaceState`, and not `pushState`, because you don't want to create a new entry in the user's browser history.

```
history.replaceState(
  '{ foo: "bar" }', 
  'Some new title', 
  'http://foo.com/Item/12345'
);
```